# Failed to build gem native extension. byebug

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to install byebug

**Error**

```
C:\Users\mushi\Projects\Sites\simple_cms>gem install byebug -v 1.6.0
Fetching: columnize-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed columnize-0.3.6
Fetching: byebug-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating byebug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
cc1.exe: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:217:0,
                 from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:29,
                 from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./byebug.h:4,
                 from breakpoint.c:1:
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:320:44: error: 'struct timespec' decla
red inside parameter list
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:320:44: error: its scope is only this
definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/win32.h:321:43: error: 'struct timespec' decla
red inside parameter list
make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-1.6
.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-1.6.0/ext/byebug/gem
_make.out
```

**My Environment**

```
C:\Users\mushi\Projects\Sites\simple_cms>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby21/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - C:/Users/mushi/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/", "http://rubygems.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Why do you want to start a version that old?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
gem 'byebug', github: 'deivid-rodriguez/byebug'
```

in gem file instead of

```
gem byebug -v 1.6.0
```